# Services provided by Android Bluetooth API with a paired phone

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

Suppose I have two android phones (say Phone A and Phone B). I have paired them through the normal bluetooth pairing procedure. I am developing an app which I will install only on Phone A.

1. What all data points/events might I be able to get from Phone B through this app by using android bluetooth APIs?
2. What if instead of Phone B, I have any other bluetooth device that you can think of. What all data points/events might I be able to get?

I'm assuming that my other option could be to build a companion app on Phone B which would talk to the app on Phone A and provide any of the data (say notifications) through providers or accessibility.

Bonus: Any thoughts if Phone B is an iPhone :)

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody has given an answer for this, let me summarize my understanding so far.

When it comes to bluetooth, we can go with some of the predefined bluetooth profiles that are available in the bluetooth standard. We can access any data that is available through the profiles that are supported by the device.